# Assign variable in a select inside an insert

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to get the assignment of a variable inside a select which runs inside an insert.

```
INSERT INTO myTable
            (Value1,Value2,Value3)
            VALUES
            (
            (
                    SELECT 'SomeText' + @MyGuid = lower(convert(varchar(36), newid())) + '"Some more text" />' AS Value1,
                    @MyGuid AS Value2,
                    columnX AS Value3 FROM myOtherTable));
```

Essentially, I need to use the same variable twice, but the assignment gets flagged with

```
Incorrect syntax near '='.
```

I tried changing the assignment syntax, but it did not help.
I need the Guids to be the same.
Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `CTE` by selecting the `NEWID()` value for each row beforehand, then transforming it per column on the `INSERT`:

```
;With ToInsert As
(
    Select  lower(convert(varchar(36), newid())) As MyGuid,
            ColumnX As Value3
    From    MyOtherTable
)
Insert  MyTable
        (Value1, Value2, Value3)
Select  'SomeText' + MyGuid + '"Some more text" />' As Value1,
        MyGuid As Value2,
        Value3
From    ToInsert
```